# How to recognize windows 10 using Python?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.6

```
import platform 
if platform.release() == 'post2008Server' and platform.version() ==   '6.2.9200':
     print "It's windows 8"
```

I have used this before to recognize Windows 8.
But it's returning same for Windows 10. So is there any other way to recognize it ?

Comment: I don’t have a Windows 10 here atm., can you check [`platform.win32_ver`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#windows-platform)?

Comment: If everything fails, you could call the `systeminfo` executable using `subprocess` and parse the information it gives you.

Comment: Cannot repro; I get `10.0.10586` from both `version()` and `win32_ver()`

Comment: @poke. I tried with platform.win32_ver(), I got this:('post2008Server', '6.2.9200', '', u'Multiprocessor Free'). Which is same as for Win 8

Comment: What Python version are we talking about?

Comment: @Poke. I am using Python 2.6

Comment: Note that Python 2.6 effectively ended support in 2013, so it may well be that Python 2.6 simply does not support the fine-grained Windows version detection here. You should consider upgrading to Python 2.7 (which should be mostly painless), or even a current Python 3 release (3.5 at the moment).

Comment: In Python 2.6? `subprocess.Popen('ver', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]`

Answer (score 6):

With the following Python versions everything works fine.

Python 3.5.1:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.release()
'10'
>>> platform.version()
'10.0.10240'
```

Python 2.7.11

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.release()
'10'
>>> platform.version()
'10.0.10240'
```

How about upgrading to at least 2.7.x ?

---

Edit: As mentioned by @Rogalski, you can always pipe the `ver` command, and this should return the following independently of the Python version:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen('ver', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
'\r\nMicrosoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]\r\n'
```

Comment: As of now I cant switch to 2.7 due to some dependencies, so I will go with second option. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Deepak, for a GUI app you can add the `Popen` option `creationflags=8` to avoid creating a console window. 8 is the value of the `DETACHED_PROCESS` flag. In this case Windows won't create or attach a console (i.e. conhost.exe) to the cmd.exe process.